# "Host has low open file limits" error in MMS

Tags: mongodb

I am running Standalone MongoDB (v 2.6.0 64-bit) host on Centos (v 6.5). Centos is guest OS on Windows 7 host running under VirtualBox (4.3.10). MongoDB process runs under root  account. And it is single mongod process on that box.

I am monitoring this instance using MMS Service. MMS shows this warning/error:

> "Host has low open file limits".

MongoDB documentation says that the following are recommended setting:

```
-f (file size): unlimited
-t (cpu time): unlimited
-v (virtual memory): unlimited 
-n (open files): 64000
-m (memory size): unlimited 
-u (processes/threads): 64000
```

I did the following in Centos:

1. Created `99-mongodb-nproc.conf` file as proscribed in `/etc/security/limits.d` with these settings:

   `root       soft    nproc     64000`
   `root       hard    nproc     unlimited`
2. In `/etc/security/limits.config` file specified this:

   `root soft nofile 64000`
   `root hard nofile 128000`
3. In `/etc/sysctl.conf` file specified this:

   `fs.file-max = 512000`

After reboot I checked

```
ulimit -a
```

And I am able to match limit setting above precisely but "Host has low open file limits" error is still there in MMS; it just would not go away no matter what I do.

If it is of any consequence I have 16GB memory on Host PC and I allocate 14GB to this guest Centos OS.

What am I still missing?

Comment: Please do not run databases as root - it's a bad, bad idea, even for testing.  If you install MongoDB using the RPM/yum then it will even take care of adding the appropriate user and the service for you.

Comment: "Please do not run databases as root - it's a bad, bad idea, even for testing" Thank you, Adam, for your note. But the way it goes I am considering switching to other database altogether. Too many issues with MongoDB, small and large, this message from MMS is just last problem in four-month long struggle with a series of never-ending issues.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the issues you are having, but running into ulimit warnings is actually a Linux system configuration issue, not an issue with MongoDB.  I know from experience (and other answers on Stack Exchange) that running databases as root is not a good idea.  How to set ulimits correctly has been asked and answered many, many times on Stack Overflow and ServerFault, so I felt that was the more important advice to give rather than provide yet another guide on setting ulimits (which will effect any database that handles lots of connections should you switch to something else).

Comment: Adam, thank you, again. Yes I did use what was suggested. #2 and #3 from my procedure above is what was able to google. And #1 from MongoDB documentation. Here is the article I used primarily: [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/). If you think it is wrong/incomplete can you please post something else or are you saying simply by switching to another user will fix my file limit issue?

Comment: When you ran ulimit -a were you logged in as root, or another user?

Comment: As it seems, limits are imposed to login sessions only. You might want to set the limits in the init script – which Simply Works™.